# Press Enter on input field to update database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made database, I have connected to it, and I get data from it as input fields. When I edit any single input field and push ENTER, I want to update my database. I need to send data to database with AJAX.
Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    //Browser Support Code
    function ajaxFunction(){
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
           }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data 
    // sent from the server and will update
    // div section in the same page.
      ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
       }
     }
     // Create variables to pass
     var id;
     var firstname ;
     var lastname ;
     var age ;

     var queryString = "?firstname=" + firstname ;
     queryString +=  "&id=" + id + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&age=" + age;
     ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
     ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <form name='myForm'>
    <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Get Database Data'/>
    </form>
    <div id='ajaxDiv' style="background-color:red">Your result will display here</div>
```

And here is **ajax-example.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "****";
$dbpass = "****";
$dbname = "ajax_example";
//Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
// Retrieve data from Query String
$id = $_GET['id'];  
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$age = $_GET['age'];

//build query
$query = "SELECT * FROM ajax_example ";

//Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Build Result String
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Id</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Firstname</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Lastname</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Age</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

// Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<td><input type='text' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";
$display_string .= "<td><input type='text' name='firstname'    value='".$row['firstname']."'></td>";
$display_string .= "<td><input type='text' name='lastname' value='".$row['lastname']."'></td>";
$display_string .= "<td><input type='text' name='age' value='".$row['age']."'> </td>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

}
echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</table>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

I am beginner, so maybe my code isn't very nice. If I have some big mistakes please tell me. But now everything I want is working fine.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: So you want listen to the `enter` key?

Comment: My problem - i need to edit my input fields ( in website, not in code ) and when i press enter in single input field, that field value is updated in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give your form an ID and put it inside of a container div. See I made a little adjustment

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="myform" name='myForm'>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="my_example_id"/>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="my_example_firstname"/>
         <input type="text" name="lastename" id="my_example_lastname"/>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="my_example_age"/>
    </form>
<div id='ajaxDiv' style="background-color:red">Your result will display here</div> 
</div>
```

And now you can just get the container by it's id and see if enter is pressed, if it is then perform a ajax query and serialize a form ( serialize means it will push all the data to ajax)

```
$(function() {
$("#container").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
         e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the default action of a enter 
            $.post('ajax-example.php',$("#myform").serialize() ,  function(response) { 
$('#ajaxDiv').html(response); // this will echo any response from ajax file
        });
    }   
});
});
```

This should do the trick

BR's

Comment: Getting errors in these lines 

    $id = $_GET['id'];   -----------                                                
    $firstname = $_GET['firstname']; ---------
    $lastname = $_GET['lastname']; ------------
    $age = $_GET['age']

Comment: is there a reason you are using GET ? ( do you need to display/ get data from url) ? Try and replace GET with POST ( in our case we are using POST )

Comment: well you should completely redo your code since you are getting data by a press of a button ( on click event ) and then what are you trying to do on enter exactly ? You should get data by php querys and then pass php variables to html for displaying. After that you can use those code lines what I provided. I edited my code a bit for a example

Answer (score 0):

You can try detecting the enter key when it's pressed make sure you also check for the currect focused text box. I'm not really professed in jQuery or Javascript but this script works for me to detect keys.
You could use jQuery further to retrieve the value from the textbox and use it further in the AJAX code.

```
<script>
    var map = {13: false};
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode in map) {
            map[e.keyCode] = true;
            if (map[13]) {

             // You code here to fire when enter is detected
                }
            }
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode in map) {
            map[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Jup , this work. Now i try to figure out my code for those input boxes.